# How to sort promises in their resolved order not caring about order in arguments

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

```
let P1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(res("R1"), 2000);
});
let P2 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(res("R2"), 5000);
});
let P3 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(res("R3"), 1000);
});
```

I expect my function to return promises in order they started like this: ["R3", "R1", "R2"]

```
function preserveOrder([P1, P2, P3]); // should return ["R3, "R1", "R2"]
function preserveOrder([P2, P3, P1]); // should return ["R3, "R1", "R2"]
```

I can't think of what the best way it is to do this? (since Promise.all()  would preserve the order)

Comment: Why are you using promises at all?

Comment: it was an interview question and I couldn't answer it, ask the recruiter xd

Comment: create an array and push an entry into it within each promise (or from a chained `.then` call) and then in `Promise.all` read that array instead of the args.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you are the one launching the promises, you know exactly in which order they started, so there is nothing to compute. Just put them in a list or something.

Comment: What is `setTimeout(res("R1"), 2000);` supposed to do?

Comment: @Liam the MSDN example is correct - the code above however invokes `res` immediately, and passes the (undefined) result to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for

```
async function fulfillmentOrder(promises) {
    const results = [];
    await Promise.all(promises.map(promise =>
        promise.then(value => {
            results.push(value);
        })
    ));
    return results;
}
```

Comment: yup, this is pretty much what I envisaged in my comment above :)

Comment: Hi, please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68579270/14032355

Comment: @ikhvjs See Jonas' and Alnitak's comments on this question

Answer (score 1):

You could map the Promises to an index once they resolve, then use `Promise.all` on them and sort them afterwards by id:

```js
let order = 0;

const result = await Promise.all(
  [P1, P2, P3].map(it => it.then(result => ({ result, position: order++ })))
);

result.sort((a, b) => a.position- b.position);
```

Alternatively one can reinvent `Promise.all` though this is something I'd generally avoid ...

```js
function PromiseAllOrdered(promises) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    const values = [];
  
    for(const promise of promises) {
      promise.then(
        value => {
          values.push(value);
          if(promises.length === values.length) resolve(values);
        },
        error => reject(error)
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: "*this is something I'd generally avoid*" - yes, and for good reason: it doesn't work for an empty `promises` array :-) Also it doesn't reject the promise when the `promises` iterator fails or a promise doesn't have a `.then()` method - you should really just put that code *inside* the executor callback. Or rather just use `Promise.all`, as one ought to.